# sticky row in listview in activity

Tags: android, listview, sticky

Just one row in my listview should be sticky .Not sections or section with alphabets in stickyheaders.I really appreciate any help w.r.t listview sticky one row within activity and not fragment.How do I do that ? I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance. 
Using code like :

```
class MyAsyncTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> UploadsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();        }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
            String... params) {

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Uploads
            uploads = json.getJSONArray(TAG_UPLOADS);

            // looping through All Uploads
            for (int i = 0; i < uploads.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = uploads.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_DATE, date);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                UploadsList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return UploadsList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

        pDialog.dismiss();

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, result,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_ID, TAG_DATE }, new int[] {
                R.id.name, R.id.id, R.id.date });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't get it. Can you explain what you want? What i get is... you want one item of list view as sticky rest item below it should scroll. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: yes perfect .That item is one of the rows whick keeps sticking on the listview all the time.

Comment: You need custom adapter for ListView to achieve you goal.

Comment: I need sticky header for 1 row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this code for Json... Hope this will solve your puzzle.. And you like this...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headerRow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/headerRow" >

        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private ArrayList<String> data;
        private TextView stickRow;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            stickRow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.headerRow);
            data = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int ak = 1; ak < 20; ak++) {
                data.add("Row " + ak);
            }

            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.activity_main));

        }

        class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

            public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
                super(context, resource);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (position == 0) {
                    stickRow.setText(getItem(position));
                }
                TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                tv.setTextSize(20);
                tv.setText(getItem(position + 1));
                return tv;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return data.size() - 1;
            }

            @Override
            public String getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return data.get(position);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: nope but I want the row to move up and down in listview like in the video which is called sticky

Comment: I seen video, try this code, this is one part of the video... try it first at you side..

Comment: its not exactly right .i should be able to move it up and down .currently with your code its not possible.

Comment: i just give you solution of "Just one row in my listview should be sticky" not whole video, and i said this can be make one part of video`s reference, we have to work on it to work in in video, this need time,,, Hope you satisfied...

Comment: Here you need multiple listView as parent-child, to work like in video.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible with only ListView.

If I would be in your position I would have used same single item layout (which is going to be used in single item of ListView) as fixed layout, below that I would have my ListView.

```
<Layout1>
    <Layout2>
        <ItemView1>
        </ItemView1>
    </Layout2>
    <ListView>
    </ListView> 
</Layout1>
```

Layout1 and Layout2 could be Relative or Linear layout

ItemView1 is the same layout which is going to be used in ListView item layout.

As my first row is going to be constant I will set the values once the view is invoked and the rest will work as usual.

Comment: Yes kind of but in the video the white image does move but in my example or the one answer given by Arfan Mirza will keep the ItemView1 or TextView (in Arfan's answer) fixed.

Comment: what should be in the itemview ? basically i used the above code its working but like i wanted ,can you edit and write the code please.I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Provide me your XML of the ListView and the single item view you are going to show in the listview.

Comment: I have used Arfan's code and its not working the way I want you can edit that code itself or any normal listview code also would do .