# In Android Development, what is the correct term for a "fixed" element?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, vocabulary

In an Android project, I'm creating a browse feature which uses a ListView to display content.

My goal is to create a fixed element which remains at the top of the screen, no matter how far down I scroll in the ListView.

What is the correct term in an Android Development environment for an item that stays on the top of the screen even after scrolling down?

As I've browsed S.O. to learn how to approach my problem, I've seen people use the word "fixed" before, but that term seems to be more associated with HTML and CSS.  I'm trying to learn what keywords I use as I search for ways to solve my problem.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Sticky. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926570/sticky-row-in-listview-in-activity

Comment: android list view header, footer. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812191/android-listview-with-fixed-header-and-footer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the term `Sticky`. According to your question you need the items to be at top always. So, it's **Sticky Header** :)

Here are some great libraries to achieve easily in quick.

1. [Header List View](http://applidium.github.io/HeaderListView/)
2. [Sticky List Headers](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders)